# Xcode 11 Beta and Carthage bootstrap

Tags: ios, carthage, xcode11, ios13

I'm trying to compile my project with Xcode 11. If I build the project I get this message:

> Module compiled with Swift 5.0 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1

I tried to rebuild dependencies running `carthage bootstrap` but I'm getting another error message from carthage:

> Unable to determine local Swift version.

Which is the best flow to run Apps built with swift 5 on Xcode 11 beta? (taking into account that I'm using carthage as dependency manager?)

Answer (score 10):

Open Xcode and goto Preferences. Now select the tab `Locations` and select `Xcode 11.0` in the dropdown menu at `Command Line Tools`. Afterwards run Carthage again and the project should build in Xcode beta.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to select the default version of XCode,
to do that just open Terminal and write this :

```
$ sudo xcode-select -s <path/to/>Xcode.app
```

make sure you put the exact path to the desired version of XCode,
or simply drag and drop it on terminal.